# How to make printf work when it is in a separate c file that is called from an s-function?

Tags: matlab, printf, simulink, mex

I have an s-function in file mySFun.c that calls a function foo() which is implemeted in a separate file myFoo.c. When I write printf statements inside the mdlOutput function in mySFun.c, they work fine. But when I put printf inside function foo() in myFoo.c they don't show their output in command window.

How can I enable printf functionality when printf is inside another file that is called from an s-function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only official way to write to the MATLAB console from a MEX-function is via the function [mexPrintf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/mexprintf.html). However, the header file mex.h includes this line:

```
#define printf mexPrintf
```

And simstruc.h includes mex.h. I suspect you are including simstruc.h from mySFun.c, but not from myFoo.c. You can either include simstruc.h or mex.h in your other source files as well (to pick up the #define there), or switch to calling mexPrintf directly.

Comment: That's correct! Since I also have to be able to use myFoo.c in a separate C project (where simstruc.h is not available) I have to do it like this: #ifdef MATLAB_MEX_FILE include simstruc.h #endif

Answer (score 1):

printf is a C-library file and as such you do not need to create yours :).  you should instead insert the myFoo.h in the mySFun.h file if you will call itz function foo().

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that because the algorithm has to be in a separate c file (not header file) due to other constraints.